# Referencing a dictionary value before creation

Tags: python

I want to create a dictionary where one value is dependent on a different value in the same dictionary.

The usual way to do this is something along the lines of:

```
>>> my_dict = {'quantity': 10}
>>> my_dict.update({'total': my_dict['quantity'] * 20})
>>> my_dict
{'quantity': 10, 'total': 200}
```

Is there a way to do this with one statement?
Here's what I thought might work, but didn't:

```
>>> my_dict = {'quantity': 10, 'total': my_dict['quantity'] * 20}
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'my_dict' is not defined
```

Comment: Not possible...

Comment: Since you know the value `10` at creation time… `'total': 10 * 20`…!?

Comment: @deceze I wanted to use a simple example for the question, obviously in my actual code both the dictionary and the used method are more complex (I calculate a hash value based on a nested dictionary).

Answer (score 2):

You can create your own dictionary:

```
class MyDict(dict):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        if 'quantity' in self:
            self['total'] = self['quantity'] * 20
```

Then this will work as you want:

```
>>> d = MyDict(quantity=10)
>>> d
{'quantity': 10, 'total': 200}
```

Of course, anyone will be able to change `total` to whatever they want, independently of `quantity`. You could override `update` and `__setitem__` to prevent direct assignments of `total` (and automatically update it when `quantity` is changed), or you may want to look into [`property`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#property).

---

If you want to pass the function to calculate `total` when you create the dictionary, as in your example, you can have a parameter for that:

```
class MyDict(dict):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.total_function = kwargs.pop('total_function', lambda x: x)
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        if 'quantity' in self:
            self['total'] = self.total_function(self['quantity'])

>>> d = MyDict(quantity=10)
>>> d
{'quantity': 10, 'total': 10}
>>> d = MyDict(quantity=10, total_function=lambda x: x * 20)
>>> d
{'quantity': 10, 'total': 200}
```

Comment: Thanks for this answer, this could work well if I had to create multiple of these dictionaries.

Answer (score 1):

It works if you have/save the value in a variable beforehand and use that:

```
n = 10
d = {'quantity': n, 'total': n * 20}
```

Comment: Presumably the value is in a variable anyway; if `10` was hardcoded the entire question would be pretty pointless…

Comment: @deceze True, which is why I modified "save" to "have/save"

Comment: Okay, so basically you are saying the answer to the question is "no"? I know what variables are, this wasn't the question.

Comment: @martonbognar Obviously it is not possible with the exact example you posted (otherwise it would have worked without raising a `NameError`). This is IMO the easiest way to get it to work. If you really don't know the values before the dictionary comprehension, you will have to do it as a second step afterwards.